# $_SESSION check if empty and redirect

Tags: php

How to check if `$_SESSION['myusername']` is empty and if so redirect them to `index.html`?

I'm currently using:

```
<?php
session_start();
/*** begin the session ***/
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
{
    header('Location:index.html');
}
?>
```

But that lets non-authorized users to stay.

Comment: Try if(empty($_SESSION['myusername'])) and remove the extra ;

Comment: In order to avoid warnings, try `!isset($_SESSION['myusername']) || (empty($_SESSION['myusername']))`

Comment: @Tom your edit turns everything upside down.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    /*** begin the session ***/
    if(empty($_SESSION['myusername']))
    {
    header('Location:index.html');;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: According to PHP manual, empty returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE. 

So !isset($_SESSION['myusername']) is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
<?php
session_start();
/*** begin the session ***/
if(!$_SESSION['myusername'])
{
header('Location:index.html');;
}
?>
```

Comment: u should check if session key exists, like in Shankar Damodaran's answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use a stronger method to control access to your pages, like a RBA system...

Take a look at [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/), it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to like this:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['blah']) && empty($_SESSION['blah'])) {
  header('Location:index.html'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`exit()` or `die()` after `header()`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old; but you did not share the full code.

I know this is from this tutorial here: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

If you check your logs, you will see that a header cannot be set after HTML tags.  If you look at the code from the tutorial, you will notice he has two HTML comments at the top.

Remove those, and `PHP` will be able to set the header and redirect the user.  Otherwise, load the page in the `else` statement and serve the login form again in the `if`.  Hope this helps.

Also, I am sure you are older and wiser after two years; but this is a poor log in process and (since the code won't work verbatim) a poor tutorial.  For example, I can still get the contents of the page with `curl http://example.com/protectedpage.php` since it will not redirect me, and it will serve the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo "Success";

}else{
header("location:yoursiteurl");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.